# Remove value From nested Array in MOngodb

Tags: mongodb

How can I remove `None` From the array?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("someOBjectId"),
    "key1" : "some Value"
    "key2" : [ 
        {
            "a" : "A",
            "b" : 5,
            "c" : ["None", "some Value"]
        }, 
        {
            "a" : "dsf",
            "b" : 6,
            "c" : ["None"]
        },
        {
            "a" : "sf",
            "b" : 7,
            "c" : [ "some Value", "None"]
        },
    
    ]
}
```

How can I remove `None` while updating this document?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("someOBjectId"),
    "key1" : "some Value"
    "key2" : [ 
        {
            "a" : "A",
            "b" : 5,
            "c" : ["some Value"]
        }, 
        {
            "a" : "dsf",
            "b" : 6,
            "c" : []
        },
        {
            "a" : "sf",
            "b" : 7,
            "c" : [ "some Value"]
        },
    
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$[]` to select all elements of `key2` array
- `$pull` to remove element from `c` array

```
db.collection.updateMany({
  "key2.c": "None"
},
{
  $pull: {
    "key2.$[].c": "None"
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6GLqY8CG8eS)